# Flutter - How to create a controller in Formfield?

Tags: flutter, dart, controller, dropdown, textformfield

I am creating an address page. And I created the necessary controllers. I want a dropdown field to select countries. And a drop-down button is placed in the text form field. Because I am creating a controller for it. How to do it?

I tried. But I couldn't place a drop-down button inside a text form field. If I try on the form field, I can't use the controllers. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Eg: Here is what I want.

TextFormField(
Controller: _countryController
child: dropdownButton()
)

Code:

```
 List<String> countries = [
    'America',
    'Bahrain',
    'India',
    'Iraq',
  ];
  String? dropdownvalue;
ProductController productController = Get.find();
  final TextEditingController _countryConroller = TextEditingController();
FormField(
          builder: (
            FormFieldState<String> state) {
            return InputDecorator(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                labelText: 'Country',
                labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Color(0xffb0afaf),
                            fontSize: 20,
                            letterSpacing: 0.6),
                  hintText: 'Bahrain',
                  hintStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            color: Color(0xff5c5c5c),
                            fontSize: 17,
                            height: 3,
                            letterSpacing: 0.5,
                            decorationThickness: 6),
                          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                  ),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: dropdownvalue,
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownvalue = newValue!;
                      });
                    },
                   items: countries.map((String dropdownvalue) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: dropdownvalue,
                        child: Text(dropdownvalue,
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                color: Color(0xff2e2929),
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                letterSpacing: 0.5)),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Then how to add a dropdown to the text field? Because I need to create a controller for it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You can use container instead of TextFormField for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use DropDownButtonFormField:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<String> countries = [
    'Country',
    'America',
    'Bahrain',
    'India',
    'Iraq',
  ];

  late String? selectedCountry;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: DropdownButtonFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 2),
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.white,
            ),
            dropdownColor: Colors.white,
            value: "Country",
            onChanged: (value) {
              if(value != "Country"){
                setState(() {
                  selectedCountry = value;
                  print("country selected: $selectedCountry");
                });
              }
            },
            items: countries.map<DropdownMenuItem>((value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Pic]

Comment: Thanks. But I want to create a controller. But I am unable to create a controller inside the dropdown form.

Comment: There is no controller property for dropDownFormField. could you tell us why do you need to assign a controller to DropDFF? So that we can give you a proper answer or a workaround.